# tuple error array format

Tags: python, formatting

Just started programming python. I have a question with this error IndexError: tuple index out of range. This app is somewhat reading large amount of log files.

my example list is:

```
arrline = ['Array0', 'Array1', 'Array2', 'Array3', 'Array4', 'Array5', 'Array6:', 'Array7', 'Array8', 'Array9', 'Array10', 'Array11', 'Array12', 'Array13', 'Array14', 'Array15', 'Array16']
```

when I use

```
tmp1 = '{0}{1}{12}{5}{6}{17}'.format(*arrline)
print tmp1
```

I end up getting `IndexError: tuple index out of range`.

but when I try

```
tmp1 = '{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}'.format(*arrline)
```

It doesn't get any errors.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `{17}` would need `arrline` to have 18 items at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> IndexError: tuple index out of range.

This error tries to tell you that you're trying to get an object from the tuple which is not in the index range of the defined tuple. The `{17}` which you're trying to print doesn't exist!

But your code which request items up until `{5}` can be executed because of the 16 items in the tuple!

Try to add another item to your tuple, or change `{17}` to `{16}`

Answer (score 0):

Because your array contains 17 elements but according to `array indexing` it's `0-16`, Array Index always starts from 0 so as you are using {17} , This index is not available you start counting from 0 , That's why your getting error {17} while `tmp1 = '{0}{1}{12}{5}{6}{17}'.format(*arrline)'`